# Resolving numbers of int iterables

Tags: python, list, sorting, object, lambda

How do i resolve the below error of my code, trying to sort elements according to odd indexes:

```
numbers = [2,3,4,7,2,3,1,8,6]
numbers.sort(key=lambda n:n[1])
print(numbers)

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

<ipython-input-26-a95756aeb06b> in <lambda>(n)
      1 numbers = [2,3,4,7,2,3,1,8,6]
----> 2 numbers.sort(key=lambda n:n[1])
      3 print(numbers)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: "trying to sort elements according to odd indexes" What does this mean? Your elements are integers; they don't have "indexes".

Comment: It is happening because you pass a number from your list to the lambda then instruct lamda to return number[1] which is an operation supported only on iterables not on ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like that ?

```
>>> numbers = [2,3,4,7,2,3,1,8,6]
>>> numbers.sort() # Sort
>>> numbers = numbers[::2] # Odd
>>> print(numbers)
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8]
```